# Стоит ли учиться самому писать алгоритм или взять готовую библиотеку?

Tags: python, графы

Недавно начал учить питон, до этого опыта в языках вообще не было. Сейчас читаю книгу Адитья Бхаргава "Грокаем алгоритмы". Познакомился с алгоритмом Дейкстры, пытался написать код, на примере кода автора, который рассчитает кратчайший путь на графе от начальной точки до конечной и тут же столкнулся с естественной проблемой - он не работает. 
  Подскажите что не так с моим кодом? Если уж он совсем плох, то как лучше было бы написать его иначе? И что мне лучше сделать в следующий раз, взять для этого готовую библиотеку или снова писать самому?
  Я тут впервые, но думаю буду заглядывать часто, как лучше будет, вставлять в вопрос проблемный фрагмент кода/код целиком/отдельным файлом прикреплять?
[image: граф]

```
graph = {}
graph['start'] = {}
graph['start', 'a'] = 5
graph['start', 'b'] = 2
graph['b', 'a'] = 8
graph['a', 'c'] = 4
graph['a', 'd'] = 2
graph['b', 'd'] = 7
graph['c', 'd'] = 6
graph['c', 'fin'] = 3
graph['d', 'fin'] = 1
graph['fin'] = {} 
infinity = float('inf')
costs = {}
costs['a'] = 5
costs['b'] = 2
costs['fin'] = infinity
parents = {}
parents['a'] = 'start'
parents['b'] = 'start'
parents['in'] = None
processed = []

node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs)
while node is not None: 
    cost = costs[node]
    neighbors = graph[node]
    for n in neighbors.keys()
        new_cost = cost + neighbors[n]
        if costs[n] > new_cost:
            costs[n] = new_cost
            parents[n] = node 
    processed.append(node) 
    node = find_lowest_cost_node(costs) 


def ind_lowest_cost_node(costs):
    lowest_cost = float('inf')
    lowest_cost_node = None
    for node in costs: 
        cost = costs[node]
        if cost < lowest_cost and node not in processed
            lowest_cost = cost
            lowest_cost_node = node
    return lowest_cost_node
```

Comment: Для учёбы надо писать самому, а для работы нужно брать готовое.

Comment: А почему не учиться сразу с готовыми библиотеками? Если принцип их работы понятен.

Comment: Во-первых, лучше всего мозг формирует связи в процессе велосипедостроения. Во-вторых, мозг склонен к самообману и понятность чужой библиотеки может быть кажущейся.

Comment: Если есть работающая, отлаженная и поддерживающаяся приличной фирмой библиотека, то лучше брать библиотеку. Беда только что таких библиотек мало и они по большей части платные. Но да, для учебы надо писать самому.